# Passing VSTS Release Multi-Configuration Phase two variables, but only one multiplier

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a VSTS Release Definition that is passed two variables, the contents of which I do not control. They contain a comma separated string of Names and a comma separated string of IDs which correspond to the Names by index.

I want to use an agent phase configured with the parallelism option set to multi-configuration and the multiplier field set to the string of IDs, so the phase is run once for each ID. I also want to use the name that corresponds to the ID in that phase, but I'm not sure how to do this.

If I set the multiplier to both variables (ID and Name) it runs the phase for the Cartesian product (cross join) of the two arrays which is not desired.

Example:

```
                    IDs: "A1, A2, A3"
                  Names: "Anna, Adam, Abby"
 Runs the phase 9 times: "A1" & "Anna", "A2" & "Anna", "A3" & "Anna"
                         "A1" & "Adam", "A2" & "Adam", "A3" & "Adam"
                         "A1" & "Abby", "A2" & "Abby", "A3" & "Abby"
```

If I set the multiplier to the ID variable only it runs the phase the correct number of times, but I can't figure out how to pass the corresponding name into the phase.

Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see how the names and the IDs are related.

Comment: @DanielMann the names and IDs are related by index. So in the example above "A1" and "Anna" are related. I updated the question to help clarify.

Comment: You're not going to be able to use multipliers to accomplish what you want. Let's step back. What are these values actually used for and where do they come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make the multi-configuration phase run once for each item in the `IDs` variable, and make the both the current ID and name available for use in the phase:

1. Set the Multipliers field to the `IDs` variable as Marina Liu suggested. This runs the phase once for each `ID` with the current `ID` stored in the `IDs` variable.
2. Add an empty variable named `CurrentName` this will store the name associated with the `IDs` variable.
3. Add an inline Powershell script task into the Agent Phase containing the following commands:

`$names = "$(Names)".Split(", ",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=CurrentName]$($names[[int]"$(SYSTEM.JOBPOSITIONINPHASE)" - 1])"`

The script uses the built in `System.JobPositionInPhase` variable, which contains the index of the phase currently being run, to get the name for the current phase for the from the `Names` variable and stores it in the `CurrentName` variable.

You can use `$(CurrentName)` anywhere in the phase to get the value of the name associated with `$(IDs)`.

Comment: anyone know how to do this in bash for a build running on macOS agent?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to run the phase for three times (`A1-Anna`, `A2-Adam` and `A3-Abby`), you just need to **specify one variable** (no matter for variable IDs or Names) **as Multipliers and filter the corresponding item from the other variable**.

Such as use variable `IDs` as Multipliers and filter corresponding name from variable `Names` each time, you can use below steps:

#### 1.   Specify IDs as Multipliers

[image]

#### 2.   Get the ID for each time run on the agent phase

After specifying variable `IDs` as Multipliers, the agent will run three times: `A1`, `A2` and `A3`.

And you can get relate ID by variable **`$(IDs)`** when run on the agent phase each time:

- When run the phase `A1`, the variable `$(IDs)` value is `A1`;
- When run the phase `A2`, the variable `$(IDs)` value is `A2`;
- When run the phase `A3`, the variable `$(IDs)` value is `A3`.

#### 3.   Filter corresponding name from Names variable when each time run on the agent phase

Since you can get the ID for each time to run, you can get corresponding name with the ID by some defined rules. Such as use if condition to get the correct name, or parse ID's index and get the corresponding name etc.