# Azure DevOps - Incorrect value in System.JobPositionInPhase variable

Tags: azure-devops

I am using a multi-configuration build pipeline in Azure DevOps to build multiple versions of an application. We use the $(system.jobpositioninphase) variable to set variables for each build. This has worked well for quite a while. Sometime between January 25th and today the builds started failing because the System.JobPositionInPhase variable started returning a value of 1 for all parallel phases.

Here is an example of how we are using the variable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51091919/264650

I have created an extremely basic build pipeline to verify the issue isn't related to anything else in our pipeline.See the screenshot to see that the pipeline is configured as multi-configuration with a multiplier value of "multiplier". The value of the "multiplier" variable is "phase1,phase3".
[image]

The only task simply prints the values of those variables.[image]

But you can see on the phase2 iteration, the variable $(System.JobPositionInPhase) prints "1" instead of 2. I also have release pipelines that use this same pattern, and they are working fine. Only multi-configuration builds seem to be affected.[image]

Comment: Not sure where your question is?  I setup your case and got same behavior.  You'll probably get better support raising an issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/) or [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html).

Comment: "where my question is"? guessing may you meant "what my question is"? why did the functionality of that variable change. it previously reported 2 if it was the second phase. it is reporting the same value for all phases, a value of 1. that isn't how it worked as little as a week ago.

Comment: posted in vs dev community: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/441189/azure-devops-incorrect-value-in-systemjobpositioni.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed to be a bug by Microsoft.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/500331/view.html